# ListView not updating after ObservableCollection is changed on Button Click

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I have a `ListView` which I am updating on button click using `RelayCommand`. `ListView` is getting updated if I add items to `observableCollection` in the `ViewModel`'s constructor but not if I do it in a method after a button click.

I have spend a lot of time researching on StackOverflow and though there are many related questions I could not find an answer. What's bugging me and I am not able to understand is that it works when I add values in the constructor.

I am using `ObservableCollection`

Setting `DataContext` to View Model at Page Level
Binding `ObservableCollection` to `ListView` in XAML

**XAML Code**

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyFare"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:MyFare.ViewModel"
x:Class="MyFare.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Height="640" Margin="0,0.333,0,-0.333" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="View My Fare"  Margin="0,10,0,603"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCurrentValue" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="Enter your Current Balance" Margin="0,53,0,0" Text="{Binding CurrentBalance, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Show Fares" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding ShowFaresCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentBalance}" />
    <ListView x:Name="nbc" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10,182,10,150" ItemsSource="{Binding Charges}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="FareTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AmountToRecharge}" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0,-28,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BonusAmount}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="118.333,0,-128.333,0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewBalance}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="118,0,-229.333,0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberofRides}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="298,0,-308.333,0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="FaresPanelTemplate">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Amount to Recharge" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontFamily="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" FontSize="{StaticResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bonus Amount" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontFamily="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" FontSize="{StaticResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="New Balance" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontFamily="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" FontSize="{StaticResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Number of Rides" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontFamily="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" FontSize="{StaticResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="headerTemplate"/>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="FaresPanelTemplate"/>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="FareTemplate"/>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
        </ListView.DataContext>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**View Model**

```cs
 using MyFareFare.Library;
 using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
 using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.Windows.Input;

 namespace MyFareFare.ViewModel {
 /// <summary>
 /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
 /// <para>
 /// Use the <strong>mvvminpc</strong> snippet to add bindable properties to this ViewModel.
 /// </para>
 /// <para>
 /// You can also use Blend to data bind with the tool's support.
 /// </para>
 /// <para>
 /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
 /// </para>
 /// </summary>
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// The <see cref="BonusChargesValue" /> property's name.
     /// </summary>
     public const string ChargesListPropertyName = "ChargeList";

     public const string PageNamePropertyName = "PageName";

     public const string CurrentBalancePropertyName = "CurrentBalance";

     public const string ButtonTextPropertyName = "ButtonText";

     private string _pageName = "My Fare";

     private string _currentBalance = "";

     private string _buttonText = "Show Fares";

     private RelayCommand _showFaresCommand; 

     public ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue> _charges = null;

     public string PageName
     {
         get
         {
             return _pageName;
         }

         set
         {
             if (_pageName == value)
             {
                 return;
             }

             //  RaisePropertyChanging(ChargesListPropertyName);
             _pageName = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(PageNamePropertyName);
         }
     }

     public string ButtonText
     {
         get
         {
             return _buttonText;
         }
         set
         {
             if (_buttonText == value)
             {
                 return;
             }

             //  RaisePropertyChanging(ChargesListPropertyName);
             _buttonText = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(ButtonTextPropertyName);
         }
     }

     public string CurrentBalance
     {
         get
         {
             return _currentBalance;
         }

         set
         {
             if (_currentBalance == value)
             {
                 return;
             }

             //  RaisePropertyChanging(ChargesListPropertyName);
             _currentBalance = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentBalancePropertyName);
         }
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// Sets and gets the Charges property.
     /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
     /// </summary>
     public ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue> Charges
     {
         get
         {
             return _charges;
         }

         set
         {
             if (_charges == value)
             {
                 return;
             }

            // RaisePropertyChanging(ChargesListPropertyName);
             _charges = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(ChargesListPropertyName);
         }
     }

     public RelayCommand ShowFaresCommand
     {
         get;
         set;
     } 

     //public RelayCommand ShowFaresCommand 
     //{
     //    get
     //    {
     //        return _showFaresCommand
     //          ?? (_showFaresCommand = new RelayCommand(
     //              ()=> 
     //              {
     //                  _charges = new ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue>();
     //                  CalculateMetroFare cmcf = new CalculateMetroFare();
     //                  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentBalance))
     //                  {
     //                      _charges = cmcf.Add2ExistingCard(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentBalance));
     //                  }

     //              }));

     //    }  
     //}

    // public RelayCommand ShowFares { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
     /// </summary>
     public MainViewModel()
     {

         _charges = new ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue>();
         ShowFaresCommand = new RelayCommand(GetValues, () => { return true; });

           // if I un-comment the below section the observable is working fine.
       //Using lambda is not helping either 

        /* if (IsInDesignMode)
         {
             // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            // BonusChargesValue bnc = new BonusChargesValue();
             _charges = new ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue>();
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 10.0, BonusAmount = 5, NewBalance = 15, NumberofRides = 5 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 12.0, BonusAmount = 6, NewBalance = 17, NumberofRides = 6 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 14.0, BonusAmount = 7, NewBalance = 19, NumberofRides = 7 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 16.0, BonusAmount = 8, NewBalance = 21, NumberofRides = 8 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 18.0, BonusAmount = 9, NewBalance = 23, NumberofRides = 9 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 10.0, BonusAmount = 5, NewBalance = 15, NumberofRides = 5 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 12.0, BonusAmount = 6, NewBalance = 17, NumberofRides = 6 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 14.0, BonusAmount = 7, NewBalance = 19, NumberofRides = 7 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 16.0, BonusAmount = 8, NewBalance = 21, NumberofRides = 8 });
             _charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 18.0, BonusAmount = 9, NewBalance = 23, NumberofRides = 9 });
         }
         else
         {
             // Code runs "for real"
             _charges = new ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue>();
           //  ShowFaresCommand = new RelayCommand(GetValues, () => { return true; });

             ShowFaresCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
             {


                 CalculateMetroFare cmcf = new CalculateMetroFare();
                 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentBalance))
                 {
                     var chr = cmcf.Add2ExistingCard(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentBalance));

                     foreach (BonusChargesValue bncv in chr)
                     {
                         Charges.Add(bncv);
                     }

                 }
             });

             //_charges = new ObservableCollection<BonusChargesValue>();
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 10.0, BonusAmount = 5, NewBalance = 15, NumberofRides = 5 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 12.0, BonusAmount = 6, NewBalance = 17, NumberofRides = 6 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 14.0, BonusAmount = 7, NewBalance = 19, NumberofRides = 7 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 16.0, BonusAmount = 8, NewBalance = 21, NumberofRides = 8 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 18.0, BonusAmount = 9, NewBalance = 23, NumberofRides = 9 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 10.0, BonusAmount = 5, NewBalance = 15, NumberofRides = 5 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 12.0, BonusAmount = 6, NewBalance = 17, NumberofRides = 6 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 14.0, BonusAmount = 7, NewBalance = 19, NumberofRides = 7 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 16.0, BonusAmount = 8, NewBalance = 21, NumberofRides = 8 });
             //_charges.Add(new BonusChargesValue { AmountToRecharge = 18.0, BonusAmount = 9, NewBalance = 23, NumberofRides = 9 });
         } */


     }
     private void GetValues()
     {

         CalculateMetroFare cmcf = new CalculateMetroFare();
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentBalance))
         {
             var chr = cmcf.Add2ExistingCard(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentBalance));

             foreach (BonusChargesValue bncv in chr)
             {
                 Charges.Add(bncv);
             }

         }

     }
 }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several things here :

First of all your `ChargesListPropertyName`  is wrong, it should be "Charges" and not "ChargeList".
If you are using MVVM Light, there are far better ways to call PropertyChanged that would prevent you to make this kind of mistakes again (I'll let you check that later).

Then you have your public `ObservableCollection` Charges that is an accessor towards _charges who is also public. You should set _charges as private (and setting it to null is useless).

And finally, your ItemsSource is set to watch Charges. So wherever you update _charges outside the constructor of your viewmodel, the List will never know what happened. What I mean is that you should always update Charges and not _charges.

Do those modifications and tell us if it helps. If not, update your code to show us what you modified.

Comment: Appreciate your input. The suggestion did not work. As you can see I am already updating "Charges" in the GetValue method and not _charges. I changed the "ChargesListPropertyName" to "Charges" too. I see the values getting added to the Charges observable but only the view is not getting updated.

Comment: Please update your code on this page accordingly so that others can better see what is left to change.